# Using ToUnicode (properly, so it works)

Tags: winapi, input, unicode

I'm trying to use the `ToUnicode` function in response to receiving a `WM_KEYDOWN` notification, which sounds a lot easier than it is.

Actually, `ToUnicode` should superfluous if one simply uses `WM_CHAR`, but much to my surprise this actually does not work properly at all! Having used `WM_CHAR` in no-common-controls-programs for ages, I've just for the first time ever typed a word with a diacritic accent<sup>1</sup> only to realize that dead keys don't work at all!
As in, if I type for example ´`e`, then `WM_CHAR` is telling me `e` when it should be telling `é` (similar for other dead key combinations, such as`â`).

`ToUnicode` seems like the obvious solution according to its documentation -- unwieldy as it is, its MSDN description page states that it does exactly what I need. It does take an awful lot of parameters, but those too *seem* straighforward.

The first parameter is simply the virtual key code (`wParam`), and the second one can be obtained via `MapVirtualKey`.
The third parameter is optional, so not actually needed (that's what "optional" means, isn't it!). Here's the first surprise: If you *don't* provide the key state, the function simply fails ("no key mapped") for any key you press. Which means an extra call to `GetKeyboardState` is needed.

That leaves us with this code:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    BYTE kb[256];
    GetKeyboardState(kb);

    WCHAR uc[5] = {};

    switch(ToUnicode(wParam, MapVirtualKey(wParam, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC), kb, uc, 4, 0))
    {
    case -1: _putws(L"dead key"); break;
    case  0: _putws(L"no idea!"); break;

    case  1:
    case  2:
    case  3:
    case  4:
    _putws(uc);
    }
...
```

This outputs the proper Unicode character for every *normal* character (no big achievement, you already get that from `WM_CHAR`), but spectacularly fails for dead keys, in the exact same way (one might suspect `TranslateMessage` uses `ToUnicode` to produce `WM_CHAR`).
The shift and alt keys as well as altgr are all honored (so for example typing `µ` (altgr-m) will give me `µ` just fine), but the diacritic dead keys (like acute or circumflex) won't work. Which means if you were to try to type some French or Spanish words on my German-layout keyboard, you're without luck.

Is there a way to use this function properly, so it works? Or, alternatively, is there a different function that works properly for dead keys?

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, obviously not for the first time, but for the first time *in this context*.

Comment: Let me guess: This is LISP? ;-)

Comment: Is my coding style so terrible? GCC seems to recognize it as a kind-of-C++, at least it doesn't complain :-)

Comment: Was just a humourous comment on the absent language tag. Well, this calls for a real winapi input expert, not me. +1

Comment: Ah OK, I assumed language was pretty obvious but irrelevant for the question, since I'm probably only using the API (which is C) wrong. Unless the function is bugged, which is of course possible, too.

Comment: This seemed unlikely so I just tried WM_CHAR with a German keyboard and ^+e gives ê, `+e gives è and ´+e gives é.  As expected.  I guess your problem is something else.  You are calling TranslateMessage in your message loop?

Comment: @arx: Yes, `GetMessage(W)` followed by `TranslateMessage`, followed by `DispatchMessage(W)`

Comment: Calling `ToUnicode` yourself breaks dead key translation, so it won't work as long as you have the `WM_KEYDOWN` code above.  Have you tried `WM_CHAR` in a vanilla app?

Comment: The documentation seems pretty clear to me. `ToUnicode` and `ToUnicodeEx` don't support dead keys. They return -1 when passed a virtual key code that corresponds to a dead key. This is, of course, why they're called dead keys. You'll need to store the virtual key code and do the processing yourself. The more interesting question is why `WM_CHAR` doesn't work properly. It certainly should. Hard to diagnose the problem, it surely lies in code that you don't show.

Comment: @arx: It seems that indeed something else is breaking `WM_CHAR`. A plain vanilla test program that does nothing but process `WM_CHAR` indeed works fine (which isn't really good news, now I need to find out what's causing it in the other one... and it sure isn't something I'm aware of). You're right that `ToUnicode` by itself breaks `WM_CHAR`, too.

Comment: @CodyGray: I dissent on that. The remarks section tells that it may not be possible to translate a keypress because of previous dead keys being stored, which suggests that it does some complicated dance, remembering dead keys and adjusting whatever is output accordingly. From that, I would conclude that it is of course meant to work fine with dead keys (only not for _every_ keypress, just when it adds up to a valid character, but that's exactly what you'd want, too). Though as it turns out, I'll rather need to look into _why_ `WM_CHAR` doesn't work in that program (obsoleting `ToUnicode`).

Comment: I would recommend you to see boost::nowide and http://utf8everywhere.org

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky: Using UTF-8 is not applicable (or helpful) interfacing with the Win32 API since the Win32 API will only accept and output UTF-16 (or UCS-2, depending on Windows version) strings and characters, the exception being `WM_UNICHAR` (UTF-32). You can certainly use UTF-8 everywhere else (and that is what I'm doing by the way) but whether or not you do that is irrelevant for the present problem. It only means you have to transcode UTF 8/16 whenever you talk to the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot confirm the symptoms you describe. I used Spy++ to monitor the messages received by Notepad. Then I pressed the dead key `´`, followed by an `e`.

As you can see, the `WM_CHAR` message is absolutely correct with the Unicode character 233. That represents `é`.

```
<00001> 000F0C86 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_OEM_6 cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0D fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<00002> 000F0C86 P WM_DEADCHAR chCharCode:'180' (180) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0D fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<00003> 000F0C86 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_OEM_6 cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0D fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
<00004> 000F0C86 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'E' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:12 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<00005> 000F0C86 P WM_CHAR chCharCode:'233' (233) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:12 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<00006> 000F0C86 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'E' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:12 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
```

So `WM_CHAR` is everything you need if you just want the composed input. Otherwise, you can handle `WM_DEADCHAR` and process the input manually.

Please read the docs about [keyboard input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267.aspx#_win32_Dead_Character_Messages) on MSDN.

Comment: Yup, `WM_CHAR` is exactly what I actually want (and what I've been using all along), except it turned out it didn't work, surprise. Now I need to find out why it doesn't work in that particular program.